# PHP: Convert all numeric fields of array to ins or floats respectively

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array. Looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "2",
        "number": "2",
        "debtor_number": null,
        "name": "Ziegler",
        "firstname": "Lisa",            
        "credit": "0.00",
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "number": "3",
        "debtor_number": null,
        "name": "Ziegler",
        "firstname": "Lisa",            
        "credit": "51.20",
```

Is there a posibility convert all numeric fileds like `2` or `51.20` to ints and floats respectively (I mean not manually) ?

Manually I do it this way:

```
             foreach ($array as &$val) {
                    foreach ($val as &$value) {
                        if(is_numeric($value)){
                            if(ctype_digit($value))
                                $value= (int)$value;
                            else
                                $value = (float)$value;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the depth of your array can vary and you want it to work for all levels, you can use [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php):

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function(&$val) {
    if (is_numeric($val)) {
        if (ctype_digit($val)) {
            $val= (int) $val;
        } else {
            $val = (float) $val;
        }
    }
});
```

An [example](https://eval.in/724738).